# Database design with user data and central database updates

Tags: mysql, litedb

I am designing a windows desktop app. It uses LiteDB as the single file local db for users - using it very much as a relational database with foreign keys etc (each Table having an integer ID as primary key and references to other tables via FK integers).

It's a retro-gaming app, so 'tables' will include things such as:

System (e.g. "Sony PlayStation", "Nintendo 64")

Controller (e.g. "Sony Dual Shock")

Control (e.g. "Cross", "Start", "Select")

Because of the above, I will have to stick to using integer IDs as the primary key - I though about using the 'name', but this wouldn't work for Controls (i.e. Start will be found on many controllers).

User should be able to add and delete records as they wish (although there will be a discouraging of deleting 'standards')

The challenge is that I'm also going to host a mysql database on my server, allowing users to update their tables from this. Now this is the bit I can't get my head around.

Say they add a System "Casio Watch" to their local table. This will get an auto-gen ID (say '94'). At the same time, some updates occur on the server database and a new system is added (e.g. "Commodore Calculator") this also gets the auto-gen ID of '94.' That's conflict number 1.

You could get around the above by just appending it as a new row in the user db - getting a new ID in that. But my second worry is around foreign keys. Let's say there's a 'Manufacturers' table with a 'Biggest Seller' field. Now on the server, for Manufacturer = Commodore, the 'Biggest Seller' FK is 94 for "Commodore Calculator" However, if this Manufacturer table is imported into the user local db, then Commodore's biggest seller would be "Casio watch" - it's ID being 94 on the user db.

Forgive me if I'm being a bit slow about all this. Referential integrity is coming to mind (is that the one with update/null FKs on change??) but I don't think you can do this through LiteDB (i.e. a change in one does not cascade to related tables).

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a simple auto increment field will not work as you have accurately stated.

Either add a "server id" field to the relevant tables identifying the computer / installation the data comes from and making sure that this field is unique across all your installations. Each system / manufacturer / etc that you need to synchronise across multiple databases will have a compound primary key consisting of the server id and an auto incremented value (although, you probably need to have a separate generator to create the auto increment locally). So, "Casio Watch" would have the server id of 1 and the auto incremented value of 94. The "Commodore Calculator" would have the same auto increment value, but its server id would be different, therefore no conflict will occur.

The other option is to use universally unique id (UUID) instead of a simple auto increment field. UUIDs are guaranteed to be unique across all mysql installations (there are some limitations). In mysql you can use the [uuid()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid) function to generate a uuid.

From a system design view UUID is simpler because mysql guarantees its uniqueness within certain limitations that are described in the above link. However, UUIDs require more storage space and will have [negative impact on innodb's performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30461895/the-differences-between-int-and-uuid-in-mysql).

Comment: Perfect - thanks a lot. Interestingly, LiteDB has its own version of this built in. For those who are interested: https://github.com/mbdavid/LiteDB/wiki/Data-Structure